# Getting HTTP load failed (error code: -1004 [1:61]) on iPhone 7 plus

Tags: ios, swift, nsurl

I have a login screen, when I'm trying to login from iPhone 7 plus device, getting the above error. I can successfully login from another iphone 5s device and all other simulators.

[image]

The above one is the my plist screen shot
[image]
The above one is the error log

Comment: Are the network settings the same? Proxy, gateway, etc.

Comment: Thanks.. now I understood the problem... Device is connected in different network..

Answer (score 3):

Add following dictionary to your info.plist for resolve your problem.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>mydomain.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>TLSv1.1</string>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSRequiresCertificateTransparency</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem occur to me, after I updated my iPhone 6 to the latest iOS 11.3 version. To fix this, all I did was go to

> Settings > General > Reset > Reset Network Settings

This did the trick for me!